# C# Attempted to read or write protected memory error

Tags: c#

Addendum: it seems to run correctly when I uncheck "optimize code" which leads me to believe it is some quirky configuration problem

Firstly I am trying to run unmanaged code.  I have "allow unsafe code" checked.  It is pointing to this line of code here where I am trying to read a bitmap without using the relatively slow getpixel:

```
byte[] buff = { scanline[xo], scanline[xo + 1], scanline[xo + 2], 0xff };
```

Entire snippet is below. How can I correct this problem?

```
private const int PIXELSIZE = 4;              // Number of bytes in a pixel

BitmapData mainImageData = mainImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, mainImage.Width, mainImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, mainImage.PixelFormat);
List<Point> results = new List<Point>();

foundRects = new List<Rectangle>();

for (int y = 0; y < mainImageData.Height
{
        byte* scanline = (byte*)mainImageData.Scan0 + (y * mainImageData.Stride);

        for (int x = 0; x < mainImageData.Width; x++)
        {
            int xo = x * PIXELSIZE;
            byte[] buff = { scanline[xo], scanline[xo + 1], 
                    scanline[xo + 2], 0xff };
            int val = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);

            // Pixle value from subimage in desktop image
            if (pixels.ContainsKey(val) && NotFound(x, y))
            {
                Point loc = (Point)pixels[val];

                int sx = x - loc.X;
                int sy = y - loc.Y;
                // Subimage occurs in desktop image 
                if (ImageThere(mainImageData, subImage, sx, sy))
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x - loc.X, y - loc.Y);
                    results.Add(p);
                    foundRects.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, subImage.Width,
                                                               subImage.Height));
                }
          }
        }
```

Comment: what is the value of PIXELSIZE?

Comment: Are you sure that the image is in the form of 32bppRGB?  You do not specify or check a pixel format anywhere in your code.

Comment: Also, just set your pointer to Scan0 once before the loops and then increment it inside of the inner loop by PIXELSIZE

Comment: What's `mainImage.PixelFormat`? If it's `Format24bppRGB` then that's why you're going over.

Comment: don't you have to "pin" the memory block first?

Comment: @Steven:  No, LockBits does just that, but the OP does need to call unlock bits afterwards, which he currently does not.

Comment: @Ed: sorry, I missed the LockBits call when skimming over the code. "Nevermind"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say with the limited information we have, but I see a couple of obvious problems, one of which addresses your issue directly:

1. You are not checking the pixel format, but are assuming that it is 32bppRGB.  It is likely 24bppRGB, and that would explain the error.
2. You are reading the RGB values incorrectly; Windows internally stores bitmaps in BGR order.
3. You are not calling UnlockBits at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values xo + 1 and xo + 2 when x is mainImageData.Width - 1? They are surely walking off the reservation.

Comment: No, this is fine, x is in pixels but xo is in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the image isn't 32bpp.  it could be 24bpp, or possibly even 8 or 16 bit.

You should be getting `PIXELSIZE` from `PixelFormat` Rather than hard-coding it to 4.

Check to see that the value you are getting for Stride agrees with the Width.